# 10.4 LTS only uses one Ethernet port, driver fails to compile

Tags: networking, server, drivers

LSPCI reports they are on diffrent IRQ's 
They are both onboard. The intel system has a Linux driver but it fails to compile because it can not find Linux headers.

```
Sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-headers
```

returns that it is installed and up to date?

lspci reports it as

```
Ethernet controller: Intel corporation device 1502 (Rev 05)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `linux-headers-generic` (or `linux-headers-generic-pae` if you're running a 32-bit PAE kernel) for the headers needed to compile out-of-tree modules.